# ¿Como emular Froyo (Api Level 8, Android 2.2) en Android Studio 3.2?

Tags: android-studio, avd

He descargado la imagen de Froyo desde el ADV manager, pero al intentar emularla me aparece el siguente eror

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-qemu" is in the same location as your system image.

Emulator: emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

La imagen utiliza el ABI `"armeabi"` en vez de `"armeabi-v7a"`

Comment: ¿Tienes instalada una versión de  Android SDK tools 24 o menor?, esta puede ser una causa del problema.

Comment: Tengo instalada la versión 28 (Pie) y parcialmente instalada las versiones 27,26,25,24,23 y 22.